# Pushing a UItableview from a normal view controller to a detail view controller

Tags: mysql, ios, uitableview, push, viewcontroller

I have a UItableview custom sized inside a Viewcontroller (for certain reasons, it cannot be inside a navigationcontroller). This is set to display a number of cells based on mysql importing into core data. How do I transition it from one view controller to another when a user clicks on an unknown row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using a navigation controller, then I would just use presentViewController:animated:completion: inside the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set `delegate` to you `UITableView` then 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` will be called on your delegate when user taps on any cell. And then all you need is to find a model in your array or whatever which correspondes to that index path 
(the most common case is `[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`)
And then you can push another view controller to the navigation stack or do a modal one